# How do I specify my frame rate for an old game I installed via CD?

Tags: port-royale-2

Just for fun I installed Port Royale 2 onto my computer from the original CD. Needless to say my current computer is much faster than the computer I had when I originally bought the game. The game plays fine on my Windows 10 box, but it has an extremely high scroll speed both with the mouse and using arrow keys. I did some research and it looks like [someone with the Steam version](https://steamcommunity.com/app/12470/discussions/0/282992646969467484/) of the game had a similar problem. The ended up solving their own problem like so:

> Solved by forcing V-sync to 30 FPS through Nvidia control panel for this application ("adaptive half refresh rate"). Game must also be configured to "Execute in full screen" or the setting will not have an effect.

I also have an Nvidia video card installed, but I can't figure out where/how to specify the frame rate. I tried the Nvidia Control Panel in my system tray but it was just generic graphics card stuff without allowing me to specify application specific settings. I also installed the "GeForce Experience" control panel since that does offer game specific tuning. Unfortunately the GeForce Experience control panel doesn't pick up the game even when I point it to the install location. I assume this is because I installed it via CD instead of via something like Steam like the person who was apparently able to specify the frame rate. I don't really have a way to check this though because the few recent games I own were purchased via Steam.

So my question is how do I force 30 FPS for this game or fix the scroll rate problem a different way?

I don't know if it matters but I have a GeForce GTX  780 video card, and am running Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to right click on your desktop and click on `Nvidia Control Panel`.

1. click on `Manage 3D Settings` on the left side of the window and then click on the `Program Settings`, instead of the `Global Settings` that it opens by default.
2. Once you're in `Program Settings` tab, you have to add the
   executable of your game by clicking `Add` and pointing it to the
   location of the `.exe` file of your game.
3. When the game is added to the list, you can find `v-sync` option and
   change it to `On`.

That should lock your in-game fps to whatever the refresh rate of your monitor is (60 hz/fps, most likely), which should be good enough.

---

**Alternative Method with Riva Tuner Statistics Server (RTSS) [(Download Link)](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/rtss-rivatuner-statistics-server-download.html)**

1. Click on "+" button and add your game executable
2. Now find the executable on your applications list and click on it
3. Set "Framerate Limit" to 60 (or another desired fps limit)
4. Now minimize application to tray (Do not close it)
5. Play your game!

[image]

[(Source for RTSS guide)](https://forum.kicksonline.eu/Thread-how-to-limit-fps-in-game__261_tutorials__7_kicks-online__5)

Comment: That looks like it is the ticket. I don't see an option "forced" I just have [these options](https://imgur.com/a/dnoVA). I think "[Adaptive](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/adaptive-vsync/technology)" is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Oh, you should set it to "On". I was writing this from memory, as my desktop PC has an AMD gpu. Haven't used my laptop in a while :P

Comment: I am going to accept your answer since I feel like you've answered the question as posed even though it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Erik there are other ways to limit fps on an nvidia gpu, one involving nvidia inspector ([guide](http://www.overclock.net/t/1368777/how-to-create-custom-fps-limits-in-inspector)) and another one using [RTSS](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/rtss-rivatuner-statistics-server-download.html) (didn't find a great guide for how to do it). I haven't tried either of the ways personally, but let me know if any of these methods work and I will add it to my answer once I get home from work.

Comment: It's weird that nvidia doesn't have an easy way of limiting fps, since AMD has had an fps limit easily available within drivers for a while now...

Comment: [Here's a simple guide on limiting fps with RTSS](https://forum.kicksonline.eu/Thread-how-to-limit-fps-in-game__261_tutorials__7_kicks-online__5).
RTSS method is supposed to give you better frame rates too.

Comment: RTSS worked great and I'm not getting the crazy scroll rates anymore. Interestingly before I installed RTSS I noticed that the Nvidia Control Panel did slow the scroll speed but only for the battle screens, not the main map screen. My SWAG is this is because the battle screen uses the 3D rendering pipeline and the map screen doesn't. Regardless RTSS did fix the problem, so thanks for your help.